# galera wsrep_cluster_address value

Tags: mysql, replication, mariadb, galera, multi-master

I am trying to deploy galera multimaster replication but faced some problems, google does not solve it it seems, but I see some people had the same problems in the past.

Say, I have 3 servers

- 192.168.1.1
- 192.168.1.2
- 192.168.1.3

first I figured out that primary node has to be intianalized like this only once (init system independent below).

`/etc/init.d/mysql start --wsrep-new-cluster`

how should the `wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"` kook like on the each node?

somewhere I read it has to list **each** address on the **each** node:

like `wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2,192.168.1.3"`

Further googling showed that primary node should only have

`wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"`

then the second node:

`wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.1"`

and the thrid:

`wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.1,192.168.1.2`

Sorry if it looks too long, I have been digging up for 4 days already every day :/

Comment: You've actually got two separate questions (as best I can tell). I recommend taking the second question out of this, and posting as another question. Otherwise, it may be closed as too broad.

Comment: @RDFozz, well, I am gentoo user and it seems I forgot to check my db installation being compiled with proper SST methods (they are all disabled by default), enabled percona and rsync on compile, so the second part was just dropped.

Comment: @M.Mass - If that is the "Answer", then self-Answer.  And elaborate a little.

Comment: @RickJames, no, not really, I am still confused about what should `wsrep_cluster_address` include

Answer (score 1):

`wsrep_cluster_address` is a comma-separated list in quotation marks, with all the nodes

e.g.:

```
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3"
```

For more info see [the official documentation here](https://galeracluster.com/library/training/tutorials/wsrep-configuration.html)